# Convert interval to group

Tags: r

This is probably asked but I couldn't find a similar one: is there a way to convert the intervals to group IDs such as:

```
x <- data.frame(num = c(1:15))
x$int <- cut(x$num, 5)
```

so that

```
x$group:
1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 5 5 5
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are so close!

```
as.numeric(x$int)
#  [1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 5 5 5
```

Comment: alright... bear with me. I was just too stupid to try this. thanks!

Comment: No reason you should know that. Once you peek behind the scenes with `str(x$int)`, though, it's clear why this works.

Answer (score 4):

You can avoid the `as.numeric()` post processing if you specify `labels = FALSE`:

```
> cut(x$num, 5, labels = FALSE)
 [1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 5 5 5
```

The help page for `cut()` tells us regarding labels: `If labels = FALSE, simple integer codes are returned instead of a factor.`